# 3rd Party Add-On Blocking Site Content - How to Prevent?

Tags: browser, add-on, browser-addons

Recently I had a friend tell me that the navigation on my site was not working. After looking into the issue on his computer I realized that it was the Yahoo Toolbar (A 3rd Party Firefox Addon) that was somehow blocking the menu. I could see the menu but not access anything on the navigation menu. Once disabled the issue went away.

**My question:**

Are there methods or code that I can add to my site that will prevent (as much as possible) this kind of conflict as I obviously cannot control 3rd Party Add-Ons?

Basically are there any proactive ways to prevent *any* third party add-ons from interacting with my site? (Any browsers not just Firefox)

**Notes:**

The menu was a standard `<ul> <li>` CSS styled menu. No JS or anything fancy.

I use a hosted CMS and *cannot* use server side code. I am looking for solutions that involved only client side code. However, you can post code that uses server side if it can help prevent this issue for others who come across this question.

Comment: Sounds like a bug worth reporting to Yahoo? I'm pretty sure their toolbar isn't supposed to interact with webpages.

Comment: @WladimirPalant - I attempted to submit a bug report [here](http://feedback.help.yahoo.com/feedback.php?.src=TOOLBAR8&.done=http://toolbar.yahoo.com&.from=inproduct&.ver_ytoolbar=wctb) I hope it is the proper place =>